# Find all integers $k$ for which there exist three positive integers $a,b,c$ such that

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

$(a+b+c)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})=9+\frac{k}{abc}$

This is a question I recently stumbled upon on a math competition. I believe the Am > Gm > Hm inequality can be used to simplify this problem. But I'm getting no where, so I'm looking for new insights and methods of approaching this problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewriting, $k$ is a symmetric polynomial function in $a$, $b$, and $c$.
$$ k = (a+b+c)(bc+ac+ab) - 9abc $$

Looking at some early values of this function,

$$ (1,1,1) \mapsto 0 \\
(1,1,2) \mapsto 2 \\
(1,2,2) \mapsto 4 \\
(2,2,2) \mapsto 0 \\
(1,1,3) \mapsto 8 \\
(1,2,3) \mapsto 12 \\
(1,3,3) \mapsto 24 \\
(2,2,3) \mapsto 4 \\
(2,3,3) \mapsto 6 $$

The obvious first hypothesis is that $k$ must always be even. To show this, consider parities of the three input variables. If all three are even, then $a+b+c$, $bc+ac+ab$, and $9abc$ are all even, so $k$ is even. If two are even and one is odd, then $a+b+c$ is odd, $bc+ac+ab$ is even, and $9abc$ is even, so $k$ is even. If one is even and two are odd, then $a+b+c$ is even, $bc+ac+ab$ is odd, and $9abc$ is even, so $k$ is even. If all three are odd, then $a+b+c$, $bc+ac+ab$, and $abc$ are all odd, so $k$ is odd.

But are all non-negative even numbers in the function's image? Looking at the one input tried so far which gave result $6$ leads to a hunch:

$$ (n-1,n,n) \mapsto (3n-1)(3n^2-2n) - 9(n^3-n^2) = 2n $$

So yes, every non-negative even integer is a possible $k$, since $a=b=c$ gives $k=0$, and for positive $k=2n$, we have the solution $a=n-1, b=c=n$.

Answer (score 3):

First, rewrite it as
$$c(a-b)^2+ b(a-c)^2 + a(c-b)^2 =k$$
Now, if you check modulo $2$ you find that $k$ is even. If you put $c=b$ you also find that each $k$ of the form
$$k=2(c-a)^2 c$$
is ok (i.e. every even integer with the only exception of $0$, since $a$ and $c$ are not null by definition). But also $0$ is ok, since $a=b=c=1$ is a solution. So the solution set is that of even integers.

Comment: If I put $c=b$, I get $k=2(a-c)^2c$.

Comment: Correct thanks. Fortunately, it does not change anything